# Is possible to link one apple developer account with primary apple developer account?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

I have single apple developer account (not enterprise) for my organization. But number of application became huge and I need add more than 100 test device for provisioning. Now apple has a limitation of device support. Is there any way to link other secondary developer account with that primary account so that even though developers will work in different account for different project yet in the end all application can be published under the primary account?

Is there any guideline from Apple to handle this situation?
Is it even possible?

Comment: If you vote for close as community specific post, at least let me know which SO site I supposed to post this question. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem is that you want to use more than 100 test devices. Your proposed solution, linking multiple developer accounts will not work. There is no way to do what you propose.

Instead use a different test distribution method: TestFlight. Accessed through App Store Connect, TestFlight allows 10,000 users.